# How do I access this array using var_dump? PHP

Tags: php, var-dump

I would like to display the text 'hamsters repeat one'.

My array: 

    `a:1:{i:0;s:19:"hamsters repeat one";}`

Should I use  `var_dump`  for this? In PHP. I know how to get the array data out of the database (I am using get_post_meta a wordpress feature for this) .

Should it be something like this? :

    `var_dump $variablewhicharrayhasbeenstored;`

Thank-you

Comment: That's a serialized array. Assuming PHP.. See [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unserialize($myvar)` to decode that string into an array.